# QStacked Widget его свойства

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь создать  QLineEdit на одной странице (currentPageName : page1 , currentIndex : 0) , созданные QLineEdit-ы отображаются на всех страницах  QStacked Widget-а (sW_otchet). Хотелось бы это исправить .

```
int flanech_x = 0; // занулен в MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

void MainWindow::on_pB_flanech_clicked() // создаем строки и задаем их    расположения
{
   ++flanech_x;
   qDebug()<< flanech_x;


  if (flanech_x < n)
  {
    qDebug() << "flanech_x" <<flanech_x;
    cells[flanech_x] = new QLineEdit(this);
    ui->sW_otchet->widget(0)->layout()->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);
    // ui->sW_otchet->setCurrentIndex(1)->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);
    // ui->sW_otchet->currentChanged(0)->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);
    // ui->sW_otchet->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);

    QRect geocells;
    geocells.setX(ui->lE_fam->x() + 52);
    rast = rast +40;
    geocells.setY(ui->lE_fam->y() + ui->lE_fam->height()+rast);
    geocells.setWidth(210);
    geocells.setHeight(24);
    cells[flanech_x]->setGeometry(geocells);
    // cells[flanech_x]->setObjectName("tratata");
    cells[flanech_x]->show();

    qDebug() << rast;
    qDebug()<< "flanech " << flanech_x;


      if (flanech_x > 6)
      {
          flanech_x = 5;
          qDebug() << "1111";
      }
  }
  else
  {
      qDebug() << "нэт кода для тебя ";
      flanech_x = 4;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Добавление произвольного виджета в виджет-стек**

Конструкция

```
cells[flanech_x] = new QLineEdit(this);
ui->sW_otchet->widget(0)->layout()->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);
```

говорит о том, что в менеджер размещения `QLayout` первой страницы стека `QStackedWidget`, созданного в дизайнере, необходимо вставить поле ввода `QLineEdit`.

В обозначенной конструкции имеется ряд потенциальных проблем:

- не проверяется, существуют ли вообще страницы в стеке;
- не проверяется, содержит ли первая страница объект менеджера размещения;
- если речь о стеке, то почему индекс страницы указан константой, тем самым
  исключая работу с другими страницами.

Если предполагается, что в стек виджеты должны добавляться динамически (в процессе работы приложения), тогда не следует создавать страницы стека в дизайнере. При соблюдении этого условия процесс добавления страниц сводится к простой и корректной инструкции:

```
cells[flanech_x] = new QLineEdit(this);
int page_index = ui->sW_otchet->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);
```

Переменная `page_index` подскажет, в какую позицию стека был вставлен виджет.

Вставленное на отдельную страницу поле ввода `QLineEdit` будет растянуто по всей ширине страницы вплоть до границ самого `QStackedWidget`. Это может не устраивать ещё и по той причине, что страница должна содержать несколько виджетов. В этой ситуации создаётся виджет-обёртка, внутри которого дочерние виджеты размещаются посредством отдельного менеджера размещения `QLayout`.

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
cells[flanech_x] = new QLineEdit(this);

QWidget *page_widget = new QWidget(this);
page_widget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
page_widget->layout()->addWidget(label);
page_widget->layout()->addWidget(cells[flanech_x]);

int index = ui->sW_otchet->addWidget(page_widget);
```

**Менеджер размещения и привязка к кординатам**

Принципиально, это два противоположных подхода. В первом случае контроль за местоположением виджетов осуществляет автоматика согласно предопределённым для неё общим правилам. Во втором случае, автор кода берёт на себя всю ответственность за выравнивание виджетов в окне. В том числе и с учётом того, что оно в процессе работы приложения может быть пользователем сужено, растянуто или даже развёрнуто на весь экран.

Какой из подходов в каждой конкретной ситуации наиболее выгоден, выбирает автор кода, однако совместное использование обоих может привести к непредсказуемому результату, отличному от желаемого.

**Список указателей на виджеты**

В Qt все виджеты обычно связаны между собой отношением `родитель-ребёнок` (`parent-child`). При создании нового виджета, в его конструктор передают указатель на родителя. Эта схема позволяет контролировать состав виджетов, и в том случае, если родитель будет удалён, все его дочерние виджеты будут также автоматически удалены.

Каждый виджет в Qt содержит список указателей на дочерние виджеты, поэтому создание собственного такого же списка должно иметь под собой серьёзное основание. Что произойдёт с массивом/списком `cells`, если какой-либо из `QLineEdit` будет удалён за ненадобностью? Указатель в `cells` не изменит своего значения (не обнулится), и при обращении по нему приведёт выполнение программы к ошибке.

Свои внутренние списки указателей Qt контролирует самостоятельно, и в случае, если какой-либо из виджетов удаляется или меняет родителя, списки указателей соответствующим образом автоматически модифицируются.

Доступ к списку указателей на дочерние виджеты можно получить посредством метода `QObject::children()` или, если требуется конкретный тип или даже конкретный объект/виджет определённого типа, посредством методов `QObject::findChildren()` / `QObject::findChild()` соответственно.

Для получения всех полей ввода, существующих на текущий момент в стеке, можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
QList<QLineEdit*> objs = ui->sW_otchet->findChildren<QLineEdit*>();
foreach(QLineEdit *ledit, objs) {
    // Далее, работаем с полученным указателем на виджет.
    ...
}
```

Если при создании виджета указать ему уникальное имя `QObject::setObjectName()`, то можно получить указатель на него таким образом:

```
QLineEdit *ledit = new QLineEdit(this);
ledit->setObjectName("tra-ta-ta-1");
ui->sW_otchet->addWidget(ledit);

...

QLineEdit *ledit = ui->sW_otchet->findChild<QLineEdit*>("tra-ta-ta-1");

// Незабываем проверить указатель.
if(ledit != Q_NULLPTR) {
    ...
}
```

**Дополнение**

Попробуем применить на практике представленную выше информацию:

```
// Метод создания полей ввода.
void MainWindow::on_pB_flanech_clicked() {
   // Создаём ровно столько полей ввода, сколько страниц в стеке.
   // Предполагаем, что виджеты страниц и их менеджеры размещения
   // уже созданы в дизайнере.
   for(int i = 0, n = ui->sW_otchet->count(); i < n; ++i) {
      QWidget *page_wdg = ui->sW_otchet->widget(i);
      if(page_wdg == Q_NULLPTR) continue;

      QLayout *page_layout = page_wdg->layout();
      if(page_layout == Q_NULLPTR) continue;

      QLineEdit *ledit = new QLineEdit(this);
      ledit->setObjectName(QString("MyLineEdit%1").arg(i));

      // Добавляем новый виджет не непосредственно в сам виджет стека
      // или в его страницу, но лишь в менеджер размещения этой страницы.

      // Обратите внимание, что `ledit` автоматически сменит своего
      // родителя при добавлении в менеджер размещения, который
      // в свою очередь имеет собственного родителя - `ui->sW_otchet`.
      page_layout->addWidget(ledit);
   }
}
```

Теперь, чтобы найти поле ввода, например, на пятой странице с соответствующим индексом "4" (индексация начинается с нуля), применяем следующее:

```
// "name" будет равно "MyLineEdit4".
const QString name = QString("MyLineEdit%1").arg(4);

QLineEdit *ledit = ui->sW_otchet->findChild<QLineEdit*>(name);
if(ledit != Q_NULLPTR) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ничеси !!! Ты сатана ??? Откуда вы все знаете ??

Comment: @timob256, пожалуйста, рад был помочь :)

Comment: Извините , но  как я понял по моему вопросу . ответ :надо  самому при  переходе на другие страницы удалять   созданные элементы потому что их нельзя положить на  sW_otchet (первую страницу ) так как элементы создавались в форме

Comment: @timob, добавить виджеты и на первую страницу, и на любую другую в стеке (даже уже после создания страниц в дизайнере) Вы можете, но в этом случае необходимо производить повсеместные проверки указателей, а также не забывать указывать индекс страницы, в которую что-то добавляете. Сейчас дополню ответ.